# is there a limit to the number of author affiliations \documentclass{article} will list, and how do I increase it

Tags: affiliation

Some co-authors and I have put together an article for publication.  However, there are 11 of us, each with different affiliations, and \documentclass{article} seems to have a limit on the number of affiliations it will list (this limit seems to be 10).  How do I increase this limit?

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Fibonacheetos}

\author{Albert\thanks{Alabama} \and Bradley\thanks{Birmingham} \and Catherine\thanks{Colorado} \and Diane\thanks{Denver} \and Elaine\thanks{El Paso} \and Frank\thanks{Florida} \and Gerald\thanks{Georgia} \and Harriet\thanks{Hanover} \and Igor \thanks{Iowa} \and Justin\thanks{Joplin} \and Katy\thanks{Kansas}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

some mathy stuff

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is better if you can show example on what you looking for.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Tom and Mico, thanks for the recommendation.  I have now edited the post.

Comment: @Tom thanks for the recommendation.  I have now edited the post to clarify my intentions.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the example. However, that's not how I would like the affiliations to appear.  I have now edited the post to clarify my intentions.

Comment: @duality - Thanks for clarifying your typesetting objective. Please see the addendum I posted to my answer. BTW, you've provided some charming name choices. However, you missed a chance to write `... \and Janis\thanks{Joplin} \and ...`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `authblk` package defines an `\affil` command that links authors to affiliations (including multiple authors with the same affiliation, if needed), and it uses Arabic numerals for the footnotes, so there should be no limit. This may be what you're looking for.

Note that the `authblk` (author block) package redefines the `\author` command, too, so you can either use the "traditional" method of separation with `\and` or you can use separate `\author` macros for each author.

Answer (score 1):

It would helpful if you provided a basis for your claim that

> \documentclass{article} seems to have a limit on the number of affiliations it will list (this limit seems to be 10).

As long as individual authors listed in the argument of `\author` are separated by the keyword `\and`, there's definitely no problem having eleven or, for that matter, even more authors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Thoughts}
\author{AA \\ aaa \and BB \\ bbb \and CC \\ ccc \and DD \\ ddd \and 
        EE \\ eee \and FF \\ fff \and GG \\ ggg \and HH \\ hhh \and 
        II \\ iii \and JJ \\ jjj \and KK \\ kkk}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

---

*Update after receiving additional information from the OP*. The OP has clarified that he/she wants to display the authors' affiliations in footnotes, using the approach

```
\author{Albert\thanks{Alabama} \and Bradley\thanks{Birmingham} \and Catherine\thanks{Colorado} 
  \and Diane\thanks{Denver} \and Elaine\thanks{El Paso} \and Frank\thanks{Florida} 
  \and Gerald\thanks{Georgia} \and Harriet\thanks{Hanover} \and Igor \thanks{Iowa} 
  \and Janis\thanks{Joplin} \and Katy\thanks{Kansas}}
```

This causes a problem for the OP because (a) the `\thanks` instructions use symbols rather than numerals as footnote markers and (b) it apparently didn't occur to the designers of the `article` class to provide more than 10 separate footnote symbols. Tsk, tsk.

The fix? Load the [footmisc](https://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package with the option `symbol` or `symbol*`, i.e., either `\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}` or `\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}`. The output then becomes:

[image]

If the document has more than 16 [shudder!] joint authors, the `symbol*` option will automatically switch from symbols to numbers from author 17 onward.

If you would prefer a different set of symbolic footnote markers, or if your document has more than 16 authors [shudder again], please consult section 1.7, entitled "The `\setfnsymbol` and `\DefineFNsymbols` commands", of the user guide of the `footmisc` package for how to proceed.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much.  This fixed the situation.